# How to add KB exclusions using Azure Powershell when creating a Software Update Deployment

Tags: windows, azure, powershell

Every time I try to add a KB exclusion using `New-AzAutomationSoftwareUpdateConfiguration -ExcludedKbNumber "4476698,4506163,4339279"` the KBs all come out on the same line when I view it in my Azure AutomationAccount. I don't know if this is normal, but it seems to me like they should each be on their own line, like when you enter them manually.

I don't know if I am formatting it wrong, but the documentation says that ExcludedKbNumber is a Type String[], but other than that I cannot find anything as far as the expected format (comma separated, space separated, etc)

The [only example I have found](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/automation/update-management/deploy-updates.md#deploy-updates-across-azure-tenants) shows a simple comma separated list, as kb01,kb02,kb03, though the GUI says to submit only the ID (without the "KB")

I want to make sure these exclusions are going to work before my system patches and gets borked due to patches installing which should not have,

I have tried:

- comma separated without spaces 4476698,4506163,4339279
- with spaces 4476698, 4506163, 4339279
- with and without quotes
- every combination of the above
- stripping any extra whitespace

I tried an array, with the same results.
If I set my excludes like this:

```
$excludedKBs = "KB4476698-KB4506163-KB4339279"` #They come out of MSSQL DB as this

$excludedKBs = [string](($excludedKBs.Replace("KB","")).Replace("-"," "))
```

OR

```
$excludedKBs = [string](($excludedKBs.Replace("KB","")).Split("-")

New-AzAutomationSoftwareUpdateConfiguration -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName -Schedule $schedule -Windows -NonAzureComputer $AdFqdn -IncludedUpdateClassification $UpdateType -ExcludedKbNumber "$excludedKBs" -Duration $duration -RebootSetting Always -PreTaskRunbookName $PreScript -PreTaskRunbookParameter $PreScriptParams -PostTaskRunbookName $PostScript -PostTaskRunbookParameter $PostScriptParams | Out-Null
```

It ends up looking like this in the actual schedule:

**Actual**

[image]

I expect it to look like this:

**Expected**

[image]

Comment: @Olaf I tried that as well, with the same result

Comment: `String[]` means the cmdlet expectys an array of strings. Easiest with `New-AzAutomationSoftwareUpdateConfiguration -ExcludedKbNumber ("4476698,4506163,4339279".Split(','))`

Comment: @Theo That doesn't work either. Converting it to an array just makes it come out as a space separated list in the GUI. Wish I could attach a screenshot to show it, this is frustrating

Comment: Then, can you try casting it to `string[]` as `(string[]("4476698,4506163,4339279".Split(',')))` P.S. you can [edit] your question and insert a screenshot

Comment: @Theo thanks, images added, along with how I set the excludes and call New-AzAutomationSoftwareUpdateConfiguration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I wasn't clear in my comments and somehow the square brackets didn't show..

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/new-azautomationsoftwareupdateconfiguration?view=azps-11.0.0#-excludedkbnumber) clearly state that parameter `ExcludedKbNumber` expects an **array** of strings in case you have more than one.

What you have now tried is casting the KB numbers you split from the string into an array *back as single string again* using cast `[string]`

These code snippets below should all do what you need:

```
# create an array directly and remove all non-digit characters from each part
$excludedKBs = 'KB4476698', 'KB4506163', 'KB4339279' -replace '\D+'
```

OR

```
# create an array from the hyphen separated string and remove all non-digit characters from each part
$excludedKBs = "KB4476698-KB4506163-KB4339279" -split '-' -replace '\D+'
```

OR

```
# create an array directly using the numeric values cast to string items
[string[]] $excludedKBs = 4476698, 4506163, 4339279
```

Result from all the above is an array holding:

```
4476698
4506163
4339279
```

Then in your code, I would suggest using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for the New-AzAutomationSoftwareUpdateConfiguration cmdlet that takes a lot of parameters to help keep the code clean and easy to update

```
# create your exclusion array
$excludedKBs = "KB4476698-KB4506163-KB4339279" -split '-' -replace '\D+'

# create a Hashtable holding the parameters for the cmdlet
$configParams = @{
    ResourceGroupName            = $ResourceGroupName
    AutomationAccountName        = $AutomationAccountName
    Schedule                     = $schedule
    Windows                      = $true
    NonAzureComputer             = $AdFqdn
    IncludedUpdateClassification = $UpdateType
    ExcludedKbNumber             = $excludedKBs
    Duration                     = $duration
    RebootSetting                = 'Always'
    PreTaskRunbookName           = $PreScript
    PreTaskRunbookParameter      = $PreScriptParams
    PostTaskRunbookName          = $PostScript
    PostTaskRunbookParameter     = $PostScriptParams
}

# run the cmdlet using the Hashtable
$null = New-AzAutomationSoftwareUpdateConfiguration @configParams  # $null = ... ignores the output
```